# Directory Permission Watcher in c#

Tags: c#

I have created the program which is monitoring a directory (e.g. `\\server\share\folderXYZ`) for changed events (like created, deleted, renamed and permission changes). I also got the notification if anything changed but I can't get exact details what has changed.

For example I have changed the permission for above directory from folder properties (Properties -> Security -> Edit ->Add new user or group or change permission for user and groups). File system watcher give notification if something changed but I can't get other details like:

1. For which user permission has changed?
2. Who changed the user permissions?
3. If any new group has been added(need to get all users in the group if new group added)?
4. If any new user is added to group and who added and need to get added user details?
5. If any user or group is removed than removed group or user details?
6. If any permission is added or changed for user than what permission are added or changed?
7. If any permission are changed for group than what permission changed?

Example Scenarios:

Action: At 11am, the Admin added User A to Trainees (Existing group)

Expected Result:
Access to `\\server\share\folderXYZ` changed: `User A` now has Read access, given by Admin at 11am, because he is now member of Trainees, which has Read Access.

Hope question is clear. I have done lots of search and couldn't find the solution. Please let me know if any API or Service available or any alternatives available?

-Thanks

Comment: Are you using Active Directory?

Comment: @ravi i am not using active directory because i only need to get changed ACL and permissions whenever something changed.Is active directory needed for my requirement?

Comment: AD may have some APIs to do this. but its moot if you are not using it.

Answer (score 2):

The way to get the information you want is to use Windows Security Auditing, esp. since you want to know who made a change, not just what the change was.

The following code (and settings), produce output like this:

> 11-07-2011 17:43:10: 'Fujitsu\Grynn' changed security descriptor on file 'C:\Users\Grynn\Documents\ExcelTools\test.txt' 
>  from 
>   'D:AI(A;;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-559386011-2179397067-1987725642-1000)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)' 
>   to 
>   'D:ARAI(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-559386011-2179397067-1987725642-1000)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)' 
>   using 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe'
>
> 12-07-2011 17:55:10: 'Fujitsu\Grynn' changed security descriptor on file 'C:\Users\Grynn\Documents\ExcelTools\test.txt'
>  from 
>   'D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-559386011-2179397067-1987725642-1000)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)'
>  
>   to 
>   'D:ARAI(D;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-559386011-2179397067-1987725642-1001)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-559386011-2179397067-1987725642-1000)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)' 
>   using 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe'

Turning on Auditing has 2 steps:
1. **Use gpedit.msc to turn on "Audit Object access"** [image: Group Policy] 
2. **Modify "Auditing" for the folder you want to watch** [image: Auditing Entry for an example folder 'ExcelTools']

Now whenever a File System Change event occurs (or via polling) query the security event log.

Code to query 'Security' event log:

```
var props = new EventLogPropertySelector(new string[] { 
                "Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime",
                "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectDomainName']",
                "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']",
                "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='ObjectName']",
                "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='OldSd']",
                "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='NewSd']",
                "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='ProcessName']"  });

using (var session = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession())
{
    //4670 == Permissions on an object were changed
    var q = new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, "*[System[(EventID=4670)]]");
    q.Session = session;

    EventLogReader rdr = new EventLogReader(q);

    for (EventRecord eventInstance = rdr.ReadEvent();
            null != eventInstance; eventInstance = rdr.ReadEvent())
    {
        var elr = ((EventLogRecord)eventInstance);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}: '{1}\\{2}' changed security descriptor on file '{3}' from \n'{4}' \nto \n'{5}' \nusing '{6}'\n----\n", 
            elr.GetPropertyValues(props).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: The string "D:AI(A;;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-559386011-2179397067-1987725642-1000)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)" is in a format called SDDL. Let me know if you need code to parse the SDDL.

Comment: thanks grynn..i already working on this method to see its reliable one. it would be great if you provide some sample code for parse SDDL.

Answer (score 1):

From what i know/been reading, `FileSystemWatcher` can only tell you the file that was affected along with the change type only.

One way to go is for you to maintain a cache of the file attributes you're interested in, an in the presence of an event notifying a change, you query the cache to get the changes made and update it as necessary.

Comment: Had discussion with micosoft support team. It seems like there is no API or solutions to achieve my requirement. 
Now trying to get detail(like who changed the access or file) from event manager but its not reliable one.